# UITableView separator disappear and won't change color

Tags: uitableview, ios7

So I just updated to xcode with iOS 7. The tableview bottom separator disappear and the top one turns white when I select a cell. The separator should be light grey color like the separator above and below it in the image. I have never set the separator to be white, so I'm not sure where it came from. How can I make it so that only the background color change to a darker shade while retaining the same separator like in iOS 6?

[image]

Comment: Can we have code of table creation ? and is table in pop over view?

Comment: Most of the UI was done in storyboard static cell

Comment: The table is a facebook style slide out menu.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem and eventually found that the `Background Color` of my `Table View Cell` prototype was set to white. This is different from the background color of the cell's `Content View`. When the cell is not selected, you'll only see the content view, but when it is selected, it seems that the cell's background color is used instead of the separator color.

So the solution was to:

1. Click the disclosure arrow next to the `Table View` in Interface Builder
2. Select the `Table View Cell`
3. In the Inspector, select the `Attributes` tab
4. Change the `Background Color` to the color you want to use for the separators around the selected cell

If you're subclassing `UITableViewCell`, you can also accomplish this by setting `self.backgroundColor` in `initWithCoder:` and/or `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:`.